# Meaning of colours in htop

Tags: ubuntu, io, top, htop

Given the option:

```
[ ] Detailed CPU time (System/IO-Wait/Hard-IRQ/Soft-IRQ/Steal/Guest)
```

In `htop` (Version `1.0.1`) what are the meanings of the colours?

In the following image, I'm seeing rather a lot of what I expect is IO-Wait, but where does one determine the meaning of the colours.

[image: htop screenshot demonstrating colours]

Naturally this depends on the htop colour theme in use (default) and the terminal color scheme (solarized light here), but is there a reference?

*Note:* This normally happens to my server right before it dies, so I thought I'd ask whilst I have some time waiting for the box to recover.

Comment: Good question, just looking at it now, and wondering WTF it is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>h</kbd> will show you the legend.

It looks like in this color scheme:

#### CPU:

- blue is for low priority threads
- green is normal priority threads
- black is for io-wait

see below for more.

#### Memory:

- green is memory in use
- blue is buffer
- orange is cache

[image: htop color legend]

Comment: as a side note: htop also tracks your mouse in case you're F# buttons are bound

Comment: +1 But where did you find this information?